# why http.dart file shows empty when redirecting from import line after adding dependency , also http.get(url) method is undfined

Tags: android, ios, dart, flutter, flutter-dependencies

i am a newbie in flutter, actually i am importing http.dart file after adding dependency "http: ^0.12.0" in pubspec.yaml , but as soon as i started importing http.dart file in main.dart and redirect to http.dart file , it shows empty there also the http.get(url) is unrecognized.

thats how i am importing http.dart file :-

```
import 'package:flutter/http/http.dart' as http;
```

and this is my pubspec.yaml:-

```
   ---
cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
description: "A new Flutter application."
dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.0.0-dev.68.0 <3.0.0"
flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
name: flutter_app
shared_preferences: ^0.2.0
version: 1.0.0+1
```

any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you should import

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
```

This is how your pubspec.yaml be:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  http: any
```

Run `$flutter upgrade` to get latest flutter sdk

Comment: it says target uri does'nt exist, if importing like this!

Comment: nope! it worked ,actually i have added the dependency on wrong line .